# Difference between layer and metadata in Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bsp

I am trying to understand yocto terminology. I understood that recipe is a set of instructions used by bitbake tool to fetch the source code, configure, compile and generate the package ( software component ).

Metadata is collection of Configuration files ( .conf ), Recipes ( .bb and .bbappend ) , Classes ( .bbclass ) and Includes ( .inc ).

What I don't understand is the term 'layer'. Is the term 'layer' and 'metadata' both same or different

For example: meta-fsl-arm : Is this a layer or metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metadata is just a generic term for data describing other data as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) explains.

Layers are recipe containers (folders), so  `meta-fsl-arm is indeed a layer`.

I suggest you to read some documentation, those [slides](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/images/1/1d/Ypdd-2017.02-ELC-Portland.pdf) helped me, as well as [mega manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) and Yocto [wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score 3):

meta-layer: A meta-layer contains the meta data. meta-data means conf, classes, and recipes.

e.g:

1. meta-fsl-arm is a meta-layer which contains the meta data(configuration and mechines classes and all recipes )
2. meta-phytec is a layer which contains the meta-data(like conf files, classes, and all recipes)

Comment: What about meta-fsl-arm and other layers. Will it not contain metadata

Comment: meta-fsl-arm is a layer which contains the metadata(conf, classes and recipes)

Comment: So you are saying both are same and can be interchangeably

Comment: I modified the answer ,now you can undestand

Comment: Do meta layer consist any additional files including meta data or it only consist metadata

Comment: meta-layers are just folders, they can contain anything you want. You can put recipes, configs, patches, closed binaries, sourcecode, etc ...

Comment: @nayfe, you are obsolutely correct. we can keep any data in meta-layers like binaries,source code, patches, conf, classes and so on.,